Prisma migration error: "type "serial" does not exist" despite using PostgreSQL 15
I'm trying to run a migration in my Prisma project, but I'm encountering the error "type "serial" does not exist", even though I'm using PostgreSQL 15.8, which should support this data type.
Steps I've taken:
I've ensured that I'm using the latest version of Prisma Client (@prisma/client: "5.11.0").
I've checked my PostgreSQL version (psql -V), which is PostgreSQL 15.8.
I've cleared the Prisma cache by deleting the node_modules and prisma directories and then reinstalling dependencies (npm install).
I've tried manually executing the SQL migration in the PostgreSQL console, but I still encounter the error.
I don't have any additional PostgreSQL extensions installed (\dx only shows plpgsql).
My migration file:
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "ClosedPositions" DROP CONSTRAINT "ClosedPositions_pkey",
ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DATA TYPE SERIAL,
ADD CONSTRAINT "ClosedPositions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "OpenPositions" DROP CONSTRAINT "OpenPositions_pkey",
ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DATA TYPE SERIAL,
ADD CONSTRAINT "OpenPositions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

Error: P3006

Migration `20240920182327_change_id_to_int_in_positions` failed to apply cleanly to the shadow database. 
Error:
ERROR: type "serial" does not exist
   0: sql_schema_connector::validate_migrations
           with namespaces=None
             at schema-engine/connectors/sql-schema-connector/src/lib.rs:325
   1: schema_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at schema-engine/core/src/state.rs:276

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Is there a conflict or configuration issue that's preventing Prisma from correctly recognizing the serial data type?
I've also tried
 npx prisma migrate reset

and I get error:
Error: P3018

A migration failed to apply. New migrations cannot be applied before the error is recovered from. Read more about how to resolve migration issues in a production database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve

Migration name: 20240920182327_change_id_to_int_in_positions

Database error code: 42704

Database error:
ERROR: type "serial" does not exist

DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E42704), message: "type \"serial\" does not exist", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("parse_type.c"), line: Some(274), routine: Some("typenameType") }

many thanks for any help

psql -V only tells you the version of your command line utility.  It doesn't say anything about the server.  If you run psql, it tells you the server version in the welcome line.

The issue is serial is not a type it is essentially a macro as described in the link:

The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases). In the current implementation, specifying:


CREATE TABLE tablename (
colname SERIAL
);


is equivalent to specifying:


CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;

The error is coming from Postgres itself:
create table id_test(id integer);

alter table id_test alter column id type serial;
ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist


If you want to add an autoincremented default to the column then from here Alter Table:

ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name ADD GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]

Which using my previous example would be:
alter table id_test alter column id set not null, alter column id add generated always as identity;

The set not null is required for an identity column.

thank you! it happened on prisma migration when i was trying to change id from BigInt to Int in this model model OpenPositions {
id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
orderId  BigInt
date     DateTime
symbol   String
side     String
price    String
quantity String
}
is there something wrong with my model or is so hard to explain edge case i ran into? I want to know if maybe i was doing something incorrectly to avoid this in the future

It is because of this: @default(autoincrement()).  The model is calling for an autoincrement field and Prisma is obviously using serial(*) for that. Docs Postgresql confirm that. The fact that it cannot handle the migration is something you should bring up here Prisma Issues.

When you face the problem bigserial doesn't exist when giving  it in prisma datatype then
Run the command
npx prisma migrate dev --create only

It will generate a migration.sql file inside the generated file changed all BIGSERIAL to BIGINT
And now run the command
npx prisma migrate dev 

